# How to fix the login button working only after two or three times click after adding ajax call?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp, single-sign-on

I have added an ajax call to my code. after adding it, I am facing intermittent issue in the login button. i.e the button works only after two or three-time click.

I  am thinking of removing the timeout of 1 sec also from ajax call.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
  timeout: 1000 
});
console.log(dom, iden);

$.post("getidp", {
  dom: dom,
  iden: iden
}, function(data, status) {
 alert("test click");
  var result = $.trim(data);
  window.location = (url.substring(0, res + 5) + (result + "/") + url.substring(res + 5, url.length));
}
```

Before adding these changes The login button was navigating within 1 click. However after these changes sometimes it works only after two or three-time clicks.

Comment: The syntax seems fine at least, but there's not really anything here we can debug in order to help you. Try checking the console for errors after making the AJAX request

Answer (score 0):

First parameter of `$.post` method should be an URL to which to which an post request should be made instead of string ('getidp') in your case.

Check official documentation - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: its not related to ajax i guess

Comment: I am getting the validation from jsp file. The click button gets canceled intermittently